# Devise / CanCan 2.0 / Omniauth: What permissions are required for Omniauth signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, cancan

I am using devise, Omniauth and CanCan 2.0 for authentication / authorization. The problem is that CanCan locks down the app and prevents signin in with Omniauth. What is the minimum set of permissions required to make it work?

This seems to work:

```
can [:new, :create, :destroy], "devise/sessions"
can [:new, :create, :edit], "devise/passwords"
can :access, "devise/registrations"
can :access, :omniauth_callbacks
```

but may be too lax?

Comment: This is explained in this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131079/omniauth-devise-open-id-cancan-whats-what-and-when-do-i-use-which-solution/12131386#12131386).

Comment: Thanks for the input. Actually, everything is working, including Omniauth (through gems 'omniauth-twitter' and 'omniauth-google-oauth2'). The only issue is that I need to allow guests to access the required controller actions in order not to block devise.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done setups like this in the past, I haven't had to specify abilities for Devise in the Cancan ability file to get Omniauth to work, because the user is being created by Devise before it hits Cancan, in the method described [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview).  But maybe you're looking for something more granular?

Comment: Was that on CanCan 2.0 or an earlier version? 2.0, AFAIK, locks down all controllers (see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/tree/2.0#setup).

Comment: Oh, I see; I wasn't aware of the change in the new version of Cancan.  If that's the case, could you create an Authentication controller that you have your Users controller (and other controllers you need Cancan'd) inherit from, and add "enable_authorization" to that?  That should leave Devise outside Cancan's purview.